# Paramiko server port forward with openssh client -N option

Tags: python, paramiko, openssh

I am attempting to build a Paramiko server that just forwards ports. I adapted the code from the [demo server](https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko/blob/master/demos/demo_server.py) code

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import base64
from binascii import hexlify
import os
import socket
import sys
import threading
import traceback
import paramiko
from paramiko.py3compat import b, u, decodebytes
import logging

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

host_key = paramiko.RSAKey(filename="test_rsa.key")
logger.info("Read key: " + u(hexlify(host_key.get_fingerprint())))


class Server(paramiko.ServerInterface):
    def __init__(self):
        self.event = threading.Event()

    def check_auth_publickey(self, username, key):
        logger.info("Auth attempt with key: " + u(hexlify(key.get_fingerprint())))
        try:
            with open("client_rsa.pub.stripped", "rb") as f:
                good_key = f.read()
            good_pub_key = paramiko.RSAKey(data=decodebytes(good_key))
        except:
            logger.exception("failed to read public key")
            return paramiko.AUTH_FAILED
        if (username == "robey") and (key == good_pub_key):
            return paramiko.AUTH_SUCCESSFUL
        return paramiko.AUTH_FAILED

    def get_allowed_auths(self, username):
        return "publickey"

    def check_channel_request(self, kind, chanid):
        logger.info("inside channel request")
        return paramiko.OPEN_SUCCEEDED

    def check_channel_direct_tcpip_request(self, chanid, origin, destination):
        return paramiko.OPEN_SUCCEEDED

    def check_channel_shell_request(self, channel):
        self.event.set()
        return True

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    sock.bind(("", 2200))
    sock.listen(100)
    logger.info("Listening for connection ...")
    client, addr = sock.accept()
    logger.info("Got a connection!")

    with paramiko.Transport(client) as t:
        t.load_server_moduli()
        t.add_server_key(host_key)
        server = Server()
        t.start_server(server=server)

        # wait for auth
        chan = t.accept(20)
        if chan is None:
            logger.info("*** No channel.")
            sys.exit(1)
        logger.info("Authenticated!")

        # prompt for more information
        chan.send("Username: ")
        f = chan.makefile("rU")
        username = f.readline().strip("\r\n")
        logger.info("received username: " + username)
        chan.close()
```

And I am using this command to connect successfully:

```
ssh -i client_rsa.key -p 2200 -L 9999:localhost:4000 -T robey@localhost
```

However, when I attempt to use the -N option for the ssh client, ie:

```
ssh -i client_rsa.key -p 2200 -L 9999:localhost:4000 -T -N robey@localhost
```

the Paramiko server hangs after authenticating the client, never reaching the `check_channel_request` function. Here are the logs from the run:

```
INFO:__main__:Read key: 689f8799e649f931b116b19227dbb2a3
INFO:__main__:Listening for connection ...
INFO:__main__:Got a connection!
INFO:paramiko.transport:Connected (version 2.0, client OpenSSH_7.2p2)
INFO:paramiko.transport:Auth rejected (none).
INFO:__main__:Auth attempt with key: cdbb2439816b22a59ee036be3a953e51
INFO:paramiko.transport:Auth rejected (publickey).
INFO:__main__:Auth attempt with key: 11c470c88233719a2499f03336589618
INFO:paramiko.transport:Auth granted (publickey).
```

Is there anyway to get the Paramiko server to be able to handle this situation?

Answer (score 0):

Figured this out. The reason nothing was happening is that the tunnel forwarding is not opened until you try to use it. It turns out my tunnel wasn't being created even without the -N option. So the answer is to make sure to use the local port after creating the SSH connection.